# Limit SNMP access to VPN

Tags: security, snmp

I need to deploy about a thousand machines across the US later this year. I'm hoping to use SNMP to monitor their (collective and individual) status. The whole block will be connected via OpenVPN so I'm hoping that there is a way to limit SNMP access to this network.

The only setting I've discovered so far is to use:

> rocommunity <community name> 10.20.0.0/16

where 10.20.xx.xx is the VPN.

I don't have any other users or communities defined. Will this be sufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only use fully-configurable Net-SNMP clients, this *should* be sufficient, but I would add IPtables rules as an additional measure to block SNMP traffing from other networks outright.

Also note that on many embedded systems, you can't configure an allowed network in this form so if you have something like this in your network, you need to take this into account.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by 'fully-configurable' and 'allowed network'? I've been testing with (what I believe is) net-snmp (via CentOS) using the VPN. I hadn't planned to use IPTables as the devices need to act as routers but I will revisit this decision.

Comment: I meant "fully configurable" as a contrast to the embedded devices I mentioned in the second paragraph. The phrase "allowed network" means the "10.20.0.0/16" network you added to the `rocommunity` statement, which limits access to this network. This configuration option doesn't exist in many embedded devices with SNMP functionality. In these devices, everyone who can reach the device and knows the community name can read and/or write to the SNMP device.